# How can I add a route on a modal using react.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am using React.js but I don't achieve to switch modal. Here is my code :

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import moment from "moment";
import { Modal, version, Button } from "antd";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import { BrowserRouter, Link, Redirect, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import Clickthere from "Clickthere";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = { visible: false };
  showModal = () => {
    this.setState({
      visible: true
    });
  };
  handleOk = (e) => {
    console.log(e);
    this.setState({
      visible: false
    });
  };
  handleCancel = (e) => {
    console.log(e);
    this.setState({
      visible: false
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      (
        <div>
          <Button type="primary" onClick={this.showModal}>
            Open
          </Button>
          <Modal
            title="Basic Modal"
            visible={this.state.visible}
            onOk={this.handleOk}
            onCancel={this.handleCancel}
          >
            <p>Some contents...</p>
            <p>Some contents...</p>
            <p>Some contents...</p>
            <p style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
              Other thing?{" "}
              <BrowserRouter>
                <Link to="/clickthere">
                  <i className="fas fa-user-plus" /> Click there
                </Link>
              </BrowserRouter>
            </p>
          </Modal>
        </div>
      ),
      (
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/clickthere" component={Clickthere} />
          </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
      )
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

I achieve to open the first modal but I don't achieve when I click on "Click there" nothing happen...

Here is the code of the component Clickthere :

```
import { Modal } from "react-bootstrap";
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

const Clickthere = (props) => {
  console.log(props);

  return (
    <>
      <Modal>
        <div>
          <p>This is a test.</p>
        </div>
      </Modal>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch></Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </>
  );
};

export default Clickthere;
```

Do you know why it does not work ?

Thank you very much !

Here is my code : [My code](https://codesandbox.io/s/modal-forked-7chzd?file=/Clickthere.js)

Comment: It looks like your Modal component needs some props like `visible` but you didn't provide them to Clickthere component. Check the React DevTools to ensure the component has been rendered and edit it's props.